# document.write("a") is not appending to my document

Tags: javascript

I need to use an infinite loop in my script, so that the browser will not freeze. I have read the documentation and I think I understand that the setInterval() function just executes a function every x miliseconds, but this code doesn't work - it prints "a" just once.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
setInterval(function() {  document.write("a"); }, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong here except that you shouldn't use `document.write` : http://jsfiddle.net/Lx5yn2xm/

Comment: No this works fine http://jsfiddle.net/7mdysx90/

Comment: Everybody claiming this does (or does not) work should share the browser/version they're testing it in. There is potentially a secondary issue where some browsers persist intervals even after document.write has been called.

Comment: @JonathanSampson How is that? `document.write` opens a new document after the page has been parsed ... afaik in every browser.

Comment: @Teemu I could have sworn I saw an issue months back that was caused by a browser holding on to events even after a call to document.write.

Comment: On the other hand, @asawyer says it works, though I can see only one "a" at the linked fiddle (FF). Which browser are you using? (The jsFiddle message "document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle envioriment and might break your fiddle." makes this even more weird.)

Answer (score 6):

Once your HTML page has been loaded, a `document.write()` statement will clear the current document and start a new empty one.  That new empty one will have the original content of the document wiped out.

If you want to successively add something to the DOM on an interval, you should use DOM manipulation functions rather than `document.write()`.

For example, you could do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
setInterval(function() {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = "a";
    document.body.appendChild(span);
}, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works, I have been using document.write(something + "<br>") so everything was fine. Here I forgot about "<br>" so it was the problem. Thanks a lot.